# Why View object instance of TextView?

Tags: android, runtime-error

I did some tests in Android studio.

In my `MainActivity` class,there's a method

```
public void openActivity(View v){
    if (v instanceof TextView){
        Log.e(getLocalClassName(),"error");
    }
}
```

And In the `activity_main.xml` ,there several `TextViews` and one `Button`, all of them have one same `onClick()`

```
<SomeView
    //some properties
    android:onClick="openActivity" />
```

When I clicked all views in app on emulator, Log print

```
MainActivity:error,
```

which means v instance of TextView returns true, all of these above. But to my acknowledge, v which is type of `View`, is the `supreType` of `TextView`, and v instanceof TextView should return false.

BTW, is there anther way to check the view is the object of `TextView`?

Comment: what happened when you click on `Button`?

Comment: @kishorejethava the code in if statement is executed, my point is it shouldn't be that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because when you click a `Button`,

a Button's View will be passed to `onClick(View v)` method
since `Button` extends `TextView` the above code

```
if (v instanceof TextView)
```

is `true`

See `Button` class doc here [Button](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html)

Comment: it sure solved my puzzle that button instanceof TextView returns true.

Comment: But my point is when the onclick method is called, and the textview object is passed to the method as a View object parameter, so the type of textview is changed into View. so view instanceof TextView should return false according to my search

Comment: its called `Code to Parent reference` we use this to accept all children or subclass.

When you pass textview to that method it'll accept because its subclass of View instanceOf func would return true for both textview class and view class

please read more about inheritance and Polymorphism Java concepts to get more grip :)

Comment: Thanks, Its helpful